# how to restrict sql database to be opened in other servers?

Tags: sql-server

Currently i have a database that is attached to a named instance server with login credentials ,but at the same time if i attach the database to another server in other system ,the same gets opened.

How to deal with this?

Is there a way to restrict the database file to opened by others without valid credentials ?

Comment: if you have the `mdf` and `ldf` files, you can attach it to any instance. However starting with sql server 2014, you can create [encrypted backups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dn449489.aspx) which may be close to what you are looking for.

Comment: @ughai do encrypted backups restrict another guy to attach and retrieve the values ?

Comment: Following conditions must be met to restore encrypted backups. _The user account performing the restore must have VIEW DEFINITION permissions on the certificate or key. If you are restoring the encrypted backup to a different instance, you must make sure that the certificate is available on that instance_

Answer (score 3):

You can do a `BACKUP` with `MEDIAPASSWORD`.

Here is the T-SQL command to backup your database:

```
BACKUP DATABASE Northwind TO DISK='C:\abc.BAK' WITH MEDIAPASSWORD='abc12345'
```

Reference Links:

[Backup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @ArunGoiral , thank you for your time..but once the backup is made and restored in a system,after that i can availe the mdf and ldf files from the location know,what if i attach that to another server?correct me if im wrong

Comment: yes, once the backup has been restored, a person with access to the server can detach the related files and then restore it to another server. You should ideally have strict access control on your servers.

Comment: but there dont arise any security know?

Comment: `MEDIAPASSWORD` is a nice option. However it seems this has been removed since sql server 2012. _Beginning with SQL Server 2012, the PASSWORD and MEDIAPASSWORD options are discontinued for creating backups. It is still possible to restore backups created with passwords._

Comment: before marking as answer let me try out your ref and codes

Comment: @utility - your database and its data is only as secure as your servers. if someone has admin access to your servers. he/she can easily get the mdf and ldf files.

Comment: consider i hav attached mydb to a server..then without detaching and without accessing the server,i can take the mdf and attach to another system know !?